# where are the actual facts re html5 devicemotion and deviceorientation available?

Tags: html, devicemotion

I've been measuring and graphing deviceorientation and devicemotion on 
Firefox and Chrome on my Samsung SIII and Safari on an iPhone 6.  So far, I 
see:

using accelerationIncludingGravity with eqns 28 and 29 from Freescale 
Semiconductor's Application Note AN3461 gives correct results, without the 
sudden jumps and reverses in deviceorientation's beta and gamma when nearing or passing 90 degrees.

integrating the motion from devicemotion rotationRate gives good results
over modest periods of time.

Chrome's rotationRates are about 1/40 of true degrees/second values.

Safari's rotationRate alpha gives the rotation around the x axis (ie, 
pitch) whereas Chrome and Firefox give that rotation rate in beta.

Before I spend a lot more time rediscovering stuff, is this sort of thing 
documented somewhere?